# Accepting a new job offer while in the middle of training

Tags: professionalism, communication, resignation, training

I'd thought I'd get some thoughts on my situation.

I have been looking for a new job position while still thinking long term at my current company. I had been following the mindset that until I got a solid job offer, I should still be working at my current company like normal.

Before the job hunting began, I was already signed up for a two day training cost (~$2k). I decided to still go on with the training until again I had a solid job offer.

I now have a job offer and ready to sign the papers. The issue is that this offer has come in while I am actually doing this training right now. What can I do professionally about it?

My initial thoughts were

- in terms of compensation, upon my official resignation, I would offer to forgo paying up my unused vacation as a way to pay back for the training cost. Normally I think most would say it is the company's problem but because of the awkward timing I feel it is appropriate(?).
- in terms of notice, I could either

  - Go back to the office during the breaks in the training (the venue not too far), and give the company notice then
  - Or wait until training completes, and give them notice the next day I am back in the office

Comment: Did you request the training or was it mandated by your employer?

Answer (score 5):

Give your notice. Mention the training session that you got and state that you'll comply with whatever policies the company has regarding training. Thank them for the work experience you got from them including the training,  Tell them that you're willing to act as a resource to them while starting the new job. A show of good will along with some ability of your management to exercise discretion might allow you to dodge getting the bill for this training.

Comment: Basically my thoughts. Be open and 'correct' about it.